# do not have permission to access my drive

Tags: 16.04, permissions

I have Ubuntu 16.04.  I have two USB external drives of which root is in control.  cannot change permissions from root to username.
Have tried:
`chown -R -v username:username *`.  All that does is give permission to the lost and found folder.  Still cant copy files to new hard disk.

`chmod -R -v 777 *` changes characteristics of lost and found folder only.

How do I get Ubuntu to give me permission to my drive so I can use the drive?

Comment: Is your hard disk formatted as NTFS?

Comment: Add the output of `mount` to your question, so we can see how the drives are mounted.

Comment: What file system is on the USB ? I am guessing FAT or NTFS and with both of those ownership and permissions are set at the time of mount.

Comment: Run `journalctl --follow` in a terminal window while you connect the external drives. That will show you how the system complains.